# Spring Data Rest - Neo4j - Can't PUT new Relation that has @StartNode and @EndNode

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-data-neo4j-4

I have the following domain models:

Route entity:

```
package org.gmjm.logistics.domain;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.EndNode;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.RelationshipEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.StartNode;

@RelationshipEntity(type="ROUTE")
public class Route
{
    @GraphId
    private Long routeId;

    private Long latencyInMinutes;

    @StartNode
    private Hub originHub;

    @EndNode
    private Hub destinationHub;

    //Getters & Setters
}
```

Hub entity:

```
package org.gmjm.logistics.domain;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;

@NodeEntity
public class Hub
{
    @GraphId
    private Long nodeId;

    private String hubName;

    private Long x;
    private Long y;

    @Relationship(type="ROUTE",direction= Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Collection<Route> incomingRoutes;

    @Relationship(type="ROUTE",direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Collection<Route> outgoingRoutes;
}
```

And the following Repositories:

```
package org.gmjm.logistics.repository;

import org.gmjm.logistics.domain.Hub;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;

public interface HubRepository extends GraphRepository<Hub>
{
}

public interface RouteRepository extends GraphRepository<Route>
{
}
```

Here are the links to the other important files, on Gist to save space:
[DemoNeo4jConfig.java](https://gist.github.com/aglassman/f1e40e4413fbf7ae3eac)
[SpringDataNeo4jDemoApplication](https://gist.github.com/aglassman/0dc31986cebadfcb23a7)
[build.gradle](https://gist.github.com/aglassman/0a1c7c8bd327877109f9)

I'm running into the following exception, and have tried a lot of different things to get this to work.  I've never had an issue with posting relations in this way with spring data rest before.

Posted JSON to http:localhost:8080/routes

```
{
    "latencyInMinutes" : 1500,
    "originHub" : "http://localhost:8080/hubs/1044",
    "destinationHub" : "http://localhost:8080/hubs/1045"
}
```

Exception:

```
{
  "cause": {
    "cause": null,
    "message": "Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class org.gmjm.logistics.domain.Hub] from String value ('http://localhost:8080/hubs/1044'); no single-String constructor/factory method\n at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@207155db; line: 2, column: 30] (through reference chain: org.gmjm.logistics.domain.Route[\"originHub\"])"
  },
  "message": "Could not read document: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class org.gmjm.logistics.domain.Hub] from String value ('http://localhost:8080/hubs/1044'); no single-String constructor/factory method\n at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@207155db; line: 2, column: 30] (through reference chain: org.gmjm.logistics.domain.Route[\"originHub\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class org.gmjm.logistics.domain.Hub] from String value ('http://localhost:8080/hubs/1044'); no single-String constructor/factory method\n at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@207155db; line: 2, column: 30] (through reference chain: org.gmjm.logistics.domain.Route[\"originHub\"])"
}
```

(Server Stack)[https://gist.github.com/aglassman/0eb32f371cb2c556543d]

I've tried the obvious, like adding a constructor with a string that was parsed to ID, and one that set hubName, and a few other combination.  I'm guessing there is some JSON annotation I can use to fix this, but I can't find anything in the docs.  Any ideas?

Comment: What about a no-args constructor?

Comment: I believe I tried that.  I'll have to try that if I ever pick up this project again.